# Unable to open php_curl.dll

Tags: php, curl

I am getting this line in my error_log

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_curl.dll'
```

This is what I have done:
1. go to the folder no-debug-non-zts-20090626 but didn`t find the php_curl.dll file

so I thought Curl was not enabled.

1. I went to php.ini and the line is there extension=php_curl.dll.

I have uploaded the phpinfo() if anyone wants to take a look:

```
http://manga.cartoonstream24.com/phpinfo.php
```

I have commented the php_curl.DLL out and replaced it with extension=curl.so and now I have this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/curl.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I have recompiled apache using easyapache and enabled curlssl ( which disables Curl but has it) and curlwrapper.

Now I am getting:

```
[10-Dec-2013 11:59:57 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/homeloader.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/homeloader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[10-Dec-2013 11:59:57 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/curl.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I checked the folder /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525 and cannot find curl.so and homeloader.so

I have now run the command Locate curl.so and this is the outcome:

```
locate curl.so
/opt/curlssl/lib/libcurl.so
/opt/curlssl/lib/libcurl.so.4
/opt/curlssl/lib/libcurl.so.4.2.0
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pycurl.so
```

Any help to fix it would be appreciated.

Thank you for looking

Comment: dll is a windows extension, as your machine seems to be linux your extensions have a `.so` extension.  Plus, the phpinfo page seems to indicate that curl is active already.  I guess there's already a line like `extension=curl.so`, so comment out that `extension=php_curl.dll` line.

Comment: thnx, actually I cannot find a line with curl.so.. should I add it?

Comment: why don't you just install curl.

Comment: can u please check the edited post?

Comment: If I'm combining all elements you mention you are trying to **configure** Apache on a cPanel managed system, using EasyApache.  Now, EasyApache installs curlssl by default, which is curl + SSL support.  This looks a lot more like a server configuration issue than a programming issue, and it would be better to have people with cPanel knowledge have a look at like.  Therefore, may I suggest you ask this question on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) as non-programming related questions are out of scope here on SO.

Comment: thnx, I will try on serverfault

Comment: Did you change this line in your php.ini?  Mine initially had the Linux directory structure (/user/something)
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"

Answer (score 11):

The path seems to be Linux, `.dll` files are Windows.  You need to install cURL depending on your Linux flavor and then if it doesn't enable it, you would add to php.ini:

```
extension=curl.so
```

`.so` files are Linux libraries.

Comment out:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Comment: so  need to reinstall curl? I have a centos 6 system so I can do it using yum.

Comment: I didn't look at your `php.ini`.  If it shows that it's loaded then no, if it's not loaded then yes.

Comment: On linux, restart the server to make this change active. 'sudo service apache2 restart'

Comment: you can grep -r php_curl.dll /etc to search where the lines are

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-curl

Comment: Why when I install php on ubuntu, the php.ini file include extension .dll but not .so?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have an empty `"extension =" line in /usr/local/lib/php.ini` file:

```
grep extension /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Basically, the extension line would have no content after the equals sign. If such a line does exist, comment out the empty extension line and restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to add a windows (.dll) extension to your UNIX version of PHP. Libraries under e.g. Linux come with .so as suffix. But telling from your phpinfo() curl is already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you didn`t get the proper version of curl for your php version.
Check in php info if it is thread safe(ts) or not thread safe(nts) and download the proper curl.dll.
Hope i helped.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but I am not an expert in the field. Can you please clarify more?